# How to add a hyperlink with a new text in jQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, append

I was trying this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(#example).append("<a href="#">Some link</a>")
});
```

but it didn't work. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JQuery selector must be always between quotation (single or double), and when you're appending HTML content, always alternate between single quote and double quote. 
Try this:

```
<div id="example">
```

then onload, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#example").append("<a href='#'>Some link</a>")
});
```

You can try the code following this link: http://jsfiddle.net/cdgfsaad/

Answer (score 0):

Quote your selector and contents correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').append('<a href="#">Some link</a>')
});
```

Comment: checked this and it worked, thanks!